# Extension of UIView

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, swift2, swift-extensions

My code is written in Swift 2.0 and with a deployment target of iOS 8.0 or later. I am trying to extend UIView so that instead of using `UIView.animateWithDuration()`, I can use my custom function.  I want to take a `UIView` that's a circle and keep it so that its corner radius remains half of its height and width but, fills a square.  So the `UIView` should expand in its current shape until it reaches a rectangular bound.  I would like to use an extension on UIView. As below.

```
extension UIView {
       func customAnimation() {

       }
}
```

Code that works is.

```
let ViewFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 10, height: 10)

let View: UIView = UIView(frame: ViewFrame)

View.layer.cornerRadius = 5 
View.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
View.layer.masksToBounds = true
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration: 10.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animation: {
    View.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(100.0, 100.0)
}, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
enum AIEdge:Int {
case
Top,
Left,
Bottom,
Right,
Top_Left,
Top_Right,
Bottom_Left,
Bottom_Right,
All,
None
```

}

```
extension UIView {

//MARK:- HEIGHT / WIDTH

var width:CGFloat {
    return self.frame.size.width
}
var height:CGFloat {
    return self.frame.size.height
}
var xPos:CGFloat {
    return self.frame.origin.x
}
var yPos:CGFloat {
    return self.frame.origin.y
}

//MARK:- DASHED BORDER
func drawDashedBorderAroundView() {
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = self.frame.size.width / 2
    let borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.5
    let dashPattern1: Int = 4
    let dashPattern2: Int = 2
    let lineColor = WHITE_COLOR

    //drawing
    let frame: CGRect = self.bounds
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    //creating a path
    let path: CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()

    //drawing a border around a view
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(frame.size.height - cornerRadius)), transform: .identity)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(cornerRadius)), transform: .identity)
    path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(cornerRadius), y: CGFloat(cornerRadius)), radius: CGFloat(cornerRadius), startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2), clockwise: false, transform: .identity)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(frame.size.width - cornerRadius), y: CGFloat(0)), transform: .identity)
    path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(frame.size.width - cornerRadius), y: CGFloat(cornerRadius)), radius: CGFloat(cornerRadius), startAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2), endAngle: CGFloat(0), clockwise: false, transform: .identity)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(frame.size.width), y: CGFloat(frame.size.height - cornerRadius)), transform: .identity)
    path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(frame.size.width - cornerRadius), y: CGFloat(frame.size.height - cornerRadius)), radius: CGFloat(cornerRadius), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2), clockwise: false, transform: .identity)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(cornerRadius), y: CGFloat(frame.size.height)), transform: .identity)
    path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(cornerRadius), y: CGFloat(frame.size.height - cornerRadius)), radius: CGFloat(cornerRadius), startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: false, transform: .identity)

    //path is set as the _shapeLayer object's path

    shapeLayer.path = path
    shapeLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.frame = frame
    shapeLayer.masksToBounds = false
    shapeLayer.setValue(NSNumber(value: false), forKey: "isCircle")
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [NSNumber(integerLiteral: dashPattern1),NSNumber(integerLiteral: dashPattern2)]
    shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    //self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
}


//MARK:- ROTATE
func rotate(angle: CGFloat) {
    let radians = angle / 180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)
    self.transform = self.transform.rotated(by: radians);
}




//MARK:- BORDER
func applyBorderDefault() {
    self.applyBorder(color: UIColor.red, width: 1.0)
}
func applyBorderDefault1() {
    self.applyBorder(color: UIColor.green, width: 1.0)
}
func applyBorderDefault2() {
    self.applyBorder(color: UIColor.blue, width: 1.0)
}
func applyBorder(color:UIColor, width:CGFloat) {
    self.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = width
}


//MARK:- CIRCLE
func applyCircle() {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = min(self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width) * 0.5
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.clipsToBounds = true
}
func applyCircleWithRadius(radius:CGFloat) {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

//MARK:- CORNER RADIUS
func applyCornerRadius(radius:CGFloat) {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

func applyCornerRadiusDefault() {
    self.applyCornerRadius(radius: 5.0)
}


//MARK:- SHADOW
func applyShadowDefault()   {
    self.applyShadowWithColor(color: UIColor.black, opacity: 0.5, radius: 1)
}

func applyShadowWithColor(color:UIColor)    {
    self.applyShadowWithColor(color: color, opacity: 0.5, radius: 1)
}

func applyShadowWithColor(color:UIColor, opacity:Float, radius: CGFloat)    {
    self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    self.layer.shadowRadius = radius
    self.clipsToBounds = false
}



func applyShadowWithColor(color:UIColor, opacity:Float, radius: CGFloat, edge:AIEdge, shadowSpace:CGFloat)  {

    var sizeOffset:CGSize = CGSize.zero
    switch edge {
    case .Top:
        sizeOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -shadowSpace) //CGSizeMake(0, -shadowSpace)
    case .Left:
        sizeOffset = CGSize(width: -shadowSpace, height: 0) //CGSizeMake(-shadowSpace, 0)
    case .Bottom:
        sizeOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: shadowSpace) //CGSizeMake(0, shadowSpace)
    case .Right:
        sizeOffset = CGSize(width: shadowSpace, height: 0) //CGSizeMake(shadowSpace, 0)


    case .Top_Left:
        sizeOffset = CGSize(width: -shadowSpace, height: -shadowSpace) //CGSizeMake(-shadowSpace, -shadowSpace )
    case .Top_Right:
        sizeOffset = CGSize(width: shadowSpace, height: -shadowSpace) //CGSizeMake(shadowSpace, -shadowSpace)
    case .Bottom_Left:
        sizeOffset = CGSize(width: -shadowSpace, height: shadowSpace) //CGSizeMake(-shadowSpace, shadowSpace)
    case .Bottom_Right:
        sizeOffset = CGSize(width: shadowSpace, height: shadowSpace) //CGSizeMake(shadowSpace, shadowSpace)


    case .All:
        sizeOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0) //CGSizeMake(0, 0)
    case .None:
        sizeOffset = CGSize.zero
    }

    self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    self.layer.shadowOffset = sizeOffset
    self.layer.shadowRadius = radius
    self.clipsToBounds = false
}


func addBorderWithColor(color:UIColor, edge:AIEdge, thicknessOfBorder:CGFloat)  {

    // dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        var rect:CGRect = CGRect.zero

        switch edge {
        case .Top:
            rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.width, height: thicknessOfBorder) //CGRectMake(0, 0, self.width, thicknessOfBorder);
        case .Left:
            rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: thicknessOfBorder, height:self.width ) //CGRectMake(0, 0, thicknessOfBorder, self.height);
        case .Bottom:
            rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.height - thicknessOfBorder, width: self.width, height: thicknessOfBorder) //CGRectMake(0, self.height - thicknessOfBorder, self.width, thicknessOfBorder);
        case .Right:
            rect = CGRect(x: self.width-thicknessOfBorder, y: 0, width: thicknessOfBorder, height: self.height) //CGRectMake(self.width-thicknessOfBorder, 0,thicknessOfBorder, self.height);
        default:
            break
        }

        let layerBorder = CALayer()
        layerBorder.frame = rect
        layerBorder.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(layerBorder)
    }
}


func animateVibrate() {

    let duration = 0.05

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration ,
                               animations: {
                                self.transform = self.transform.translatedBy(x: 5, y: 0)
    },
                               completion: { finish in

                                UIView.animate(withDuration: duration ,
                                                           animations: {
                                                            self.transform = self.transform.translatedBy(x: -10, y: 0)
                                },
                                                           completion: { finish in


                                                            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration ,
                                                                                       animations: {
                                                                                        self.transform = self.transform.translatedBy(x: 10, y: 0)
                                                            },
                                                                                       completion: { finish in


                                                                                        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration ,
                                                                                                                   animations: {
                                                                                                                    self.transform = self.transform.translatedBy(x: -10, y: 0)
                                                                                        },
                                                                                                                   completion: { finish in

                                                                                                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration){
                                                                                                                        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                        })
                                                            })
                                })
    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You really just have to move the animation logic into the extension function like this

```
extension UIView {
    func customAnimtation() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(100.0, 100.0)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}


let ViewFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 10, height: 10)
let View: UIView = UIView(frame: ViewFrame)
View.layer.cornerRadius = 5
View.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
View.layer.masksToBounds = true
View.customAnimtation()
```